# MATLAB: Modify multiple line object

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot, line

I can plot multiple disconnected line segments in MATLAB using:

```
x1=[0 1 .2];
y1=[0 2 1];
x2=[1 .5 .8];
y2=[1 -1 -.5];
lh=line([ x1' x2' ]',[ y1' y2' ]');
```

[image: Plotting multiple line segments in MATLAB]

Here `x1` and `y1` are the arrays of the x- and y-coordinates of the start points, and `x2` and `y2` of the end points.

`lh` is the handler of the multiple line object created:

[image: Multiple line object]

However, I cannot modify the data of this object using the traditional `set` as for a single line:

```
>> set(lh, 'XData', [ x1' x2' ]');
Error using matlab.graphics.primitive.Line/set
While setting the 'XData' property of Line:
Value must be a vector of numeric type
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Additional info: querying its XData yields:

```
>> lh.XData

ans =

     0     1


ans =

    1.0000    0.5000


ans =

    0.2000    0.8000
```

Answer (score 2):

That's weird. I tried doing that, just out of curiosity:

```
set(lh, 'XData', get(lh, 'XData'));
```

...but received the same error.

As a workaround, you could modify the struct array directly like this:

```
for ii = 1:numel(lh)
    lh(ii).XData = [x1(ii) x2(ii)];
end
```

Comment: It's not really that weird, the error is pretty explicit. You're trying to pass an array to `XData` when it needs to be a vector, and it errors out. The `line` call creates three separate line objects, all with separate properties.

Comment: Sure, you're right. My point was I thought it was weird for the `set(...get(...))` to raise that error (not the error itself, but the fact it was raised). If you run only the `get` on the 3-object array, you'll see it returns a cell array with 3 cells (one vector for each object). I thought the appropriate action for the `set` would be to distribute each cell value to each object. That would be consistent, on my opinion.

Comment: It does this, you just have to use the correct syntax: `set(lh, {'XData'}, get(lh, 'XData'))`. See: ['Set Line Style to Different Value for Multiple Lines' in the `set` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. I was updating my answer, but I saw you already posted yours.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have created three line objects, not just one, you need to set the properties for each individually. The most explicit option is to loop through the line objects and set the properties accordingly, but you also have two other options:

**1. Using documented features of `set`**

If you look at [the documentation for `set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) it provides a syntactically similar example under the 'Set Line Style to Different Value for Multiple Lines' heading:

```
P = plot(rand(4));
NameArray = {'LineStyle'};
ValueArray = {'-','--',':','-.'}';
set(P,NameArray,ValueArray)
```

Which we can adapt to our working example:

```
x1=[0 1 .2];
y1=[0 2 1];
x2=[1 .5 .8];
y2=[1 -1 -.5];
lh=line([ x1' x2' ]',[ y1' y2' ]');

newdata = {[0 1]; [2 1]; [3 0]};
set(lh, {'XData'}, newdata);
```

Which produces a new plot:

[image: sample image]

**2. Using a variant of `deal` with the new handle graphics structure**

As you noticed, you can now address all of the properties directly using the dot notation because [MATLAB's graphics handles are now objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html). We can take advantage of this using a variant of the [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) function, found under the 'Example 3 — Doing the Same Without deal' heading in the documentation, to distribute our cell array of data to their respective `XData` properties:

```
x1=[0 1 .2];
y1=[0 2 1];
x2=[1 .5 .8];
y2=[1 -1 -.5];
lh=line([ x1' x2' ]',[ y1' y2' ]');

newdata = {[0 1]; [2 1]; [3 0]};
[lh.XData] = newdata{:};
```

Which produces the same result.

Comment: As I said on my answer's comment section, I was going to update it then I saw your answer. Anyway, I'll post my contribution here. Since the OP already have the `x1` and `x2` vectors, one possible approach is to do this: `set(lh, {'XData'}, num2cell([ x1' x2' ], 2))`.